Nexe: How to "force include" libraries that are not included in the build
I built an application that uses pinojs for logging. However, when I build the exe for Windows targets, some of its dependencies are not made part of the output build. See error below.

I would like to know if there is a way to force include modules that are missing from the .exe file. After reading the documentation, there is an option called bundle that seems to be the solution for these cases, but I have not been able to get it working.
Thanks in advance.
